# Getting position and orientation from RGBDSLAM?

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm buiding a robot equipped with a kinect sensor that will navigate a room autonomously or based on manually entered waypoints. I'd like to use rgbdslam to map out the environment the robot is in, and since it of course also does localization, I was wondering how to extract the kinects coordinates and orientation from rgbdslam. Any help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11181/getting-position-and-orientation-from-rgbdslam?/) by [pdowling](https://answers.ros.org/users/971/pdowling/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-09-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you explored the tf tree rgbdslam generates for you?  It seems slam_transform is the localized position of the kinect.

---

Originally posted by [redbaron148](https://answers.ros.org/users/1021/redbaron148/) with karma: 66 on 2011-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer of redbaron is correct.
In the new snapshot (see installation instructions [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam/evaluation)) there is a fixed frame (by default called "map" and positioned where the first frame is taken) and a transformation to the "openni_camera" frame is given from there.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-10-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1